# How to overwrite object in array instead of adding new

Tags: javascript

```js
var foo = [];

var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var data = {
       "id": 1,
       "track": {
           "map_name": [
               {x: 21, y: 21}
           ]
       }
   }
   foo.push(data);
   console.log(foo);
});
```

```html
<button id="foo">Add</button>
```

Here I'm adding whole object to array every time I click "add". Which is bad and I know it. And I'm wondering, how I can overwrite only track inside object with id 1 for example, and add new object to that `"map_name"` array. So I prevent cloning the same object over and over with new values. How can I archive that?

Comment: Did you try to use `foo[itemIndex].track = data.track` instead of `foo.push(data) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work. Just try it
Try something like this

```
let newData = [];
newData = data;
foo = newData;
```

Here newData array get you data object and insert and its equaling for foo array without pushing. so always foo array only has the value from newData array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array, use an object whose keys are the track IDs. Then you can find or create the element for the track you're interested in, and update its `map_name` array.

```js
var foo = {};

var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var cur_track = foo[1] || {
    id: 1,
    track: {
      map_name: []
    }
  };
  cur_track.track.map_name.push({
    x: 21,
    y: 21
  });
  console.log(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may give you an inspiration to solve the issue

```
var foo = [];

var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var targetId = 1;
  var targetIndex = foo.findIndex(f => f.id === targetId); // check if foo already have the id
  var coordinate = {
    x: 21,
    y: 21
  };

  // if found
  if (targetIndex > -1) {
    // push the coordinate inside `map_name` for target 
    foo[targetIndex].track.map_name.push(coordinate);
  } else {
    var data = {
      "id": targetId,
      "track": {
        "map_name": [
          coordinate
        ]
      }
    }
    foo.push(data);
  }

  console.log(foo);
});
```